# Simple bootloader and bochs

Tags: assembly, bootloader, att, bochs, yasm

I have a simple bootloader written in AT&T syntax.

```
[bits 16]
[org   0x7c00]
jmp   $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw    0xaa55
```

I use `yasm -f bin -o boot.bin loader.s` to compile it, and bochs to run.

```
dd if=boot.bin bs=512 of=floppy.img
bochs -q
```

But `bochs` said that there is `no bootable device`.

So, I have the following questions:

1. How can I rewrite it with AT&T syntax (which construction I must use instead `times 510-($-$$) db 0)`?
2. What is wrong with bochs?

Thanks!

P.S. `Bochs` was compiled with `x86_64` support, but it doesn't work with `bochs` from the official arch repo.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you stick with the Intel syntax as it is usually more readable than AT&T. For a few basic differences between them you can check [this](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) and [this](https://www.acrc.bris.ac.uk/acrc/RedHat/rhel-as-en-4/i386-syntax.html).

On Ubuntu, bochs needs `bochs-x` and `bochs-sdl` in order to run without errors. Then you should be able to boot from your floppy image with:

```
bochs -q 'display_library: sdl' 'boot:a' 'floppya: 1_44=floppy.img, status=inserted'
```

Another option is to use `qemu` instead of `bochs`:

```
qemu -fda floppy.img
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't imagine why you're trying to write AT&T syntax if you don't know AT&T syntax! I think the "times" line would be...

```
.org 0x7DFE
.word 0xAA55
```

Bochs is probably looking for an entire 1.44M floppy image.

Comment: *Bochs is probably looking for an entire 1.44M floppy image* - No, you can feed Bochs with smaller files.