# Memory Read Error in the default BOCHS BIOS

Tags: bios, bochs, floppy

I am debbuging a floppy with BOCHS using the default BIOS. It errors at fffffff0 which is in the bios. It has the following error:
`bx_dbg_read_linear: physical memory read error (phy=0x0000322f3130, lin=0x00000000322f3130)`

Other people have had this issue but say it is because BOCHS automatically adds a breakpoint. I am following a turtorial and they just add another breakpoint later and continue. When I continue, it gives ***The Same Error*** at ***The Same Time***.
Help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bochs: can not load bootloader using a floppy image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067357/bochs-can-not-load-bootloader-using-a-floppy-image) . NOte there is an answer that discusses the breakpoints but the other answers and comments point out a bug in newer Ubuntu builds that requires you to download BOCHS source and build it yourself.